# Using rescue on assignment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

I'm trying to rescue from a fault that might happen upon an assignment. I can rescue from nil no problem, but what if I want to take a couple actions?

For example, this works fine:

```
new_object = Product.find_by_id(412) rescue nil
```

However, I want to print something and take another action. So how would I get something like this to work:

```
new_object = Product.find_by_id(412) rescue nil
                                        puts "what happened"
                                        next
                                     end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following

```
begin
  new_object = Product.find_by_id(412)
rescue
  new_object = nil
  puts 'what happened'
  next
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  foo = Product.find_by_id!(412)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  logger.warn "Could not find foo" 
end
```